# What is the meaning of "a tad glib"?

Tags: meaning

What does the principal mean? (from *The Simpsons*)

[*Marge brings Principal Skinner into the living room.*]

Pr. Skinner: Mr. and Mrs. Simpson, we have transcended incorrigible. I don't think suspension or expulsion will do the trick. I think it behooves us all to consider... deportation.

Marge: Deportation!? You mean, kick Bart out of the country?

Pr. Skinner: Well, perhaps ***I was being a tad glib***. Let me explain...

Answer (score 2):

{As a recent questioner, welcome to the site; please read the site tour and please include your own research when you ask questions}.

What did you find when you looked in the dictionary for "tad" and "glib"? You probably saw something like this:

> tad (noun) mainly UK informal
> a tad: a little, slightly
>
> "The fish was OK, but the chips were a tad greasy."
>
> glib (adjective) = speaking or spoken in a confident way, but without careful thought or honesty:
>
> "He's a glib, self-centred man."
>
> [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/tad)

The description of *tad* as a noun (Merriam Webster also does this) seems to lead to a confusing noun-adjective combination in "tad glib" that obscures its idiomatic use. It is used in this phrase as a modifier for *glib*, and the whole phrase means *tending to be glib*, *a little glib*, *slightly glib*.

Answer (score 1):

Here is AHD on **glib**

> Given to or characterized by **fluency of speech or writing** that often suggests **insincerity, superficiality, or a lack of concern.**

And **a tad**, as defined by the same dictionary, means

> To a small degree; somewhat

Thus Pr. Skinner is saying that he doesn't completely stand by what he'd said previously: **suspension**, **expulsion**, **deportation**, *yadda yadda yadda.*